# Reading a config file from a server using Javascript (no CORS or jsonp)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to read a config file from a server (that I do not control). It seems like neither CORS (just getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource") nor jsonp is supported by the server (the file is a simple text file and jsonp just fails to parse the response).

Is there a way to just read the config file directly in javascript or do I have to use a proxy in this case? If so, are there any online proxies I could use so that I don't need to set up my own?

The file itself is at http://labs.funspot.tv/worktest_color_memory/colours.conf

Comment: You must use a proxy.

Comment: I was afraid of that, oh well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No luck with anything I tried to load it normally, so a proxy it is.

I did find this blog-post that shows how to use yahoo as a proxy. For testing purposes this was great for me as I really didn't want to have to set up a proxy (I had no use of running python/php/whatever except for this). For a real deploy yql is probably not the thing, but when doing a demo it was just what I needed.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax